# Inherit resolvers from graphql interface with Apollo Server v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I would like to inherit resolvers from a graphql interface.

Consider this schema.

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  interface Name {
    name: String!
    surname: String!
  }

  type Person implements Name {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    surname: String!
  }

  type Query {
    getPerson: Person!
  }
}
```

And these resolvers:

```
const queryResolver = {
  Name: {
    name: () => "John",
    surname: () => "Doe"
  },

  Query: {
    getPerson: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return {
        _id: "1",
      };
    },
  }
}
```

This is my server

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = require("./types");
const queryResolvers = require("./resolvers/query");

const resolvers = {
  Query: queryResolvers.Query,
  Name: queryResolvers.Name,
};
try {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
  server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`Apollo server listening on ${url}`);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

I would like that when querying the server

```
query Query {
  getPerson {
    name
    surname
  }
}
```

I get John Doe, as I would expect that `Person` inherits the resolvers from `Name`.

On ApolloServer v.2 I get this functionality implemented through `inheritResolversFromInterfaces` https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/graphql-tools/

I have not been able to find and equivalent on ApolloServer v3.0

Answer (score 0):

The only option I could find is by creating the schema by using [makeExecutableSchema](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/generate-schema#makeexecutableschema) from the `@graphql-tools/schema`, and then [passing that schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server#options) to the ApolloServer constructor:

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    inheritResolversFromInterfaces: true,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
    ...otherApolloArguments,
    schema,
});
```